# Query in SQL to display all the details of the employees whose commission is more than their salary

Tags: sql

Please help for the task
Display all the details of the employees whose commission is more than their salary and
create additional column – “Salary_range” of employees that are Managers or Salesmen for their salary range in following groups “Less than 2000”, “Between 2000 and 5000” and “More than 5000”, for all other employees(not Manager and neither Salesman) value should be ’MISSING’.

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE commission>salary
```

begins but then how should it proceed?

Sample table: employees

```
emp_id | emp_name | job_name  | manager_id | hire_date  | salary  | commission | dep_id
-------|----------|-----------|------------|------------|---------|------------|--------
 68319 | KAYLING  | PRESIDENT |            | 1991-11-18 | 6000.00 |            |   1001
 66928 | BLAZE    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-05-01 | 2750.00 |            |   3001
 67832 | CLARE    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-06-09 | 2550.00 |            |   1001
 65646 | JONAS    | MANAGER   |      68319 | 1991-04-02 | 2957.00 |            |   2001
 67858 | SCARLET  | ANALYST   |      65646 | 1997-04-19 | 3100.00 |            |   2001
 69062 | FRANK    | ANALYST   |      65646 | 1991-12-03 | 3100.00 |            |   2001
 63679 | SANDRINE | CLERK     |      69062 | 1990-12-18 |  900.00 |            |   2001
 64989 | ADELYN   | SALESMAN  |      66928 | 1991-02-20 | 1700.00 |     400.00 |   3001
 65271 | WADE     | SALESMAN  |      66928 | 1991-02-22 | 1350.00 |     600.00 |   3001
 66564 | MADDEN   | SALESMAN  |      66928 | 1991-09-28 | 1350.00 |    1500.00 |   3001
 68454 | TUCKER   | SALESMAN  |      66928 | 1991-09-08 | 1600.00 |       0.00 |   3001
 68736 | ADNRES   | CLERK     |      67858 | 1997-05-23 | 1200.00 |            |   2001
 69000 | JULIUS   | CLERK     |      66928 | 1991-12-03 | 1050.00 |            |   3001
 69324 | MARKER   | CLERK     |      67832 | 1992-01-23 | 1400.00 |            |   1001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested [CASE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) statement.

```sql
select *
      ,case
         when JOB_ID in ('MANAGER', 'SALESMAN') then
           case
             when SALARY < 2000 then 'Less than 2000'
             when SALARY between 2000 and 5000 then 'Between 2000 and 5000'
             when SALARY > 5000 then 'More than 5000'
           end
         else 'MISSING'
       end as SALARY_RANGE
  from EMPLOYEES
 where COMMISSION > SALARY
```